Interpreting the Coriolis Deflection using the Right Hand Rule
This isn't the most math heavy or technical question. I'm just trying to make sense of the coriolis deflection of objects moving from the equator towards the poles using the right hand rule. I know that, in a rotating frame of reference, the coriolis pseudoforce is described by this term:
$- 2 m \left (\vec \omega \times \dot {\vec r} \right )$
However, I am unable to replicate the resulting cross-product using the right hand rule. I know that this can be solved mathematically (with $\vec \omega$ being in the inertial frame in polar coordinates, and $\dot {\vec r}$ in the non-inertial frame in cartesian coordinates), and I've tried doing so, but it still does not make "kinesthetic" sense to me.
In summary, what I'm asking is how should I orient my right hand to replicate the right-hand rule when dealing with the coriolis deflection. Any help is appreciated.

It's not omega cross r, it's omega cross v. Point the fingers of your right hand in the direction of omega, which would be from south to north, and curl them into the direction of the velocity of the particle. Your thumb them points in the direction of omega cross v.

Thank you! I missed a dot when typing out the expression. It should be accurate now. As for the orientation of the hand, when you say point the fingers of my right hand in the direction of omega, when I curl my fingers towards the north or the south, my thumb points either into the center of the earth, or directly away from it. What am I doing and/or assuming wrong?

Omega points north. Let's say you have a particle moving on a line of longitude towards the north at say 45 degrees latitude. The velocity then has a component pointing in towards the axis of the Earth. When you curl your right hand finders from the north towards the direction pointing in towards the axis, your thumb will point to the west.

Thank you! That makes it clear to me. I think I arrived at a similar conclusion in my answer to this question. The comments are much appreciated.

I did some thinking about this and I may have arrived at a conclusion. The very quick mental math I did for this made sense to me, but I am not sure how correct it is, so I still need some feedback.
Essentially, a body moving from the equator towards the poles (let's say from the equator towards the North pole) has a velocity $\dot{\vec r}$ that can be broken down to $\dot{\vec {r_{inward}}}$ and $\dot{\vec {r_{northward}}}$, because $\dot{\vec r}$ is bound by the curvature and gravitational pull of the Earth.
$- \left(\vec \omega \times \dot{\vec {r_{northward}}}\right) = 0$, because they are parallel vectors.
$- \left(\vec \omega \times \dot{\vec {r_{inward}}}\right) = - [C_1(-\hat{x})] = + C_1 \hat{x}$, where the positive $\hat{x}$ is eastward.
Similarly, for an object moving southward from the North pole towards the equator, the $\dot{\vec r}$ can be broken down to  $\dot{\vec {r_{outward}}}$ and $\dot{\vec {r_{southward}}}$.
Initially, at the pole, there is no $\dot{\vec {r_{southward}}}$. However, as the object moves further south, bound by the curvature and gravitational pull of the Earth, $\dot{\vec {r_{southward}}}$ begins to manifest.
$- \left(\vec \omega \times \dot{\vec {r_{southward}}}\right) = 0$, because they are parallel vectors.
$- \left(\vec \omega \times \dot{\vec {r_{outward}}}\right) = - [C_2 (+ \hat{x})] = - C_2 \hat{x}$, where the negative $\hat{x}$ is westward.
Is this line of thinking correct?
